# How to save particular file before build jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I save particularly files before a build jenkins ? 
My build Jenkins will build a wixproj (to create .msi) but the wix proj download big files (500Mo) so the build is very slow ... 45 mins... i want to save particularly files (.msm) but my build clean his workspace each times.

Comment: have you tried the archiveArtifact and [Copy artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

Even your question is not very clear, but I'm suggesting on what I understood. You can mention the particular build to save it forever from configuration page.

Tick on the below option:

> keep this build forever

But let me tell you one thing, It will help to save the particular build to keep you in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

After your source code is downloaded to folder, You can copy required files to your destination before build the your source code. you can use robocopy for copying files via windows batch command in jenkins.

for file copy :

`copy "D:\Jenkins\workspace\SourceFile" "D:\Jenkins\workspace\TargetFile" /Y`

for folder copy:

`(robocopy "D:\Jenkins\workspace\SourceFolder" "D:\Jenkins\workspace\TargetFolder" /e /np /R:5 /mt:64 /XD IGNORE) ^& exit 0`